# Async callback was not invoked jest/supertest - simple endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, timeout, supertest

I'm not calling an external API endpoint, I just want to test my own local endpoint with supertest/jest. Setting a timeout obviously won't solve my problem because this is a extremely simple request. I'm calling done on this request so I don't understand what is wrong here.

```
router.get('/photo', Photo.getFromRequest, function (request, res) {
  // making this simple just for the first step
  return res.status(200).send
})
```

```
jest.mock('../models/photo', () => ({
  getFromRequest: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ id: xxx })
}))

const photo = require('./photo')
const request = require('supertest')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.use('/', photo)
describe('validate photo endpoint', () => {
  it('returns 200 and object photo link/image', function (done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/photo')
      // assert things later
      .end(function (err, res) {
        done(err)
      })
  })
})
```

```
   : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

Comment: In that example it fails *without* the middleware, because you never send the response - you're missing parentheses on `.send`. Note you don't need a mock return value from middleware - the return value isn't used.

Comment: Good spot, but it's still failing..

Comment: For the same reason? Please update to give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the express [Router-level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) are called with (req, res, next), they do something (for example applying properties to the request or the response) and call the callback and don't return anything.

So you should probably mock it to actually call the `next` callback like this:

```
jest.mock('../models/photo', () => ({
  getFromRequest: jest.fn().mockImplementation((req, res, next) => {
    req.photo = { id: xxx };
    next();
  })
}))
```

**Edit:** to check if the middleware have been called you can also import it in the test

```
import { getFromRequest } from '../models/photo'

// ...your mock and other tests here
// and after you've executed the request you may assert
expect(getFromRequest).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying this implementation for sometime but I can see I was close. How can I use this to expect(middleware).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1). Assigning it to a variable and using it in this expectation doesn't work..